# How can I generate a dynamic description text for bokeh plot outside of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, python, html, bokeh, interactive

I have a bokeh plot with several glyphs and a javascript callback function that blends in additional glyphs based on where the mouse hovers in the plot.

Now I want to add a description with additional information on the right side outside of that plot based on where the mouse hovers (or maybe clicks) in the left side plot.

How can I generate a dynamically changing description text for a bokeh plot outside of the canvas?

My idea was to write a java script callback function that changes the text of a div outside the plot, but I am not sure if that is possible or how to accomplish that.

Using a hover tool would be possible but the descriptions I have are too long to be displayed as an overlay box.

Here is some sample code with the div I would like to change dynamically:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, HoverTool, Div, Spacer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row

output_file("hover_callback.html")

# define some points and a little graph between them
x = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7]
y = [6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5]
links = {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [0, 3, 4],
    2: [0, 5],
    3: [1, 4],
    4: [1, 3],
    5: [2, 3, 4]
}

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="", toolbar_location=None, title='Hover over points')

source = ColumnDataSource({'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []})
sr = p.segment(x0='x0', y0='y0', x1='x1', y1='y1', color='olive', alpha=0.6, line_width=3, source=source, )
cr = p.circle(x, y, color='olive', size=30, alpha=0.4, hover_color='olive', hover_alpha=1.0)

# Add a hover tool, that sets the link data for a hovered circle
code = """
const links = %s
const data = {'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []}
const indices = cb_data.index.indices

console.log(cb_data.index.indices)

for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    const start = indices[i]
    for (var j = 0; j < links[start].length; j++) {
        const end = links[start][j]
        data['x0'].push(circle.data.x[start])
        data['y0'].push(circle.data.y[start])
        data['x1'].push(circle.data.x[end])
        data['y1'].push(circle.data.y[end])
    }
}
segment.data = data
""" % links

callback = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr.data_source, 'segment': sr.data_source}, code=code)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback, renderers=[cr]))


div = Div(text="""<br>
Here is were I want to display some additional information about the point that is currently hovered over.""",
width=200, height=100)

show(row(p,Spacer(width=20), div))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, HoverTool, Div, Spacer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import row

output_file("hover_callback.html")

# define some points and a little graph between them
x = [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7]
y = [6, 4, 3, 8, 7, 5]
links = {
    0: [1, 2],
    1: [0, 3, 4],
    2: [0, 5],
    3: [1, 4],
    4: [1, 3],
    5: [2, 3, 4]
}

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="", toolbar_location=None, title='Hover over points')

source = ColumnDataSource({'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []})
sr = p.segment(x0='x0', y0='y0', x1='x1', y1='y1', color='olive', alpha=0.6, line_width=3, source=source, )
cr = p.circle(x, y, color='olive', size=30, alpha=0.4, hover_color='olive', hover_alpha=1.0)

# Add a hover tool, that sets the link data for a hovered circle
code = """
const links = %s
const data = {'x0': [], 'y0': [], 'x1': [], 'y1': []}
const indices = cb_data.index.indices

console.log(cb_data.index.indices)

for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    const start = indices[i]
    for (var j = 0; j < links[start].length; j++) {
        const end = links[start][j]
        data['x0'].push(circle.data.x[start])
        data['y0'].push(circle.data.y[start])
        data['x1'].push(circle.data.x[end])
        data['y1'].push(circle.data.y[end])
    }
}
segment.data = data
""" % links

callback = CustomJS(args={'circle': cr.data_source, 'segment': sr.data_source}, code=code)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback, renderers=[cr]))


div = Div(text="""<br>
Here is were I want to display some additional information about the point that is currently hovered over.""",
width=200, height=100)

new_code = """
console.log(div_object.text)

const indices = cb_data.index.indices

console.log(indices)

if (indices == undefined || indices.length == 0){{
    div_object.text = ""
}}
else {{
    div_object.text = " currently point with index <b>" + indices.toString(10) + "</b> is selected. Here follows a very long description... <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ornare metus at justo semper finibus. Donec malesuada ut nisl ac convallis. Nulla laoreet in metus non dictum. In odio libero, elementum sit amet mi vitae, iaculis tincidunt sem. Quisque eget auctor massa. Nunc pulvinar cursus eros vitae bibendum. Integer vitae pharetra nulla. Integer vitae iaculis ligula. Cras elementum neque magna, posuere semper leo iaculis nec. Curabitur vel neque ut massa efficitur luctus. In at enim sed est pulvinar rhoncus. Aliquam dictum venenatis interdum. Pellentesque accumsan imperdiet varius."
}}

"""

callback = CustomJS(args={'div_object': div}, code=new_code)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=None, callback=callback, renderers=[cr]))


show(row(p,Spacer(width=20), div))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example, it does exactly what you want:https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html?highlight=event#customjs-for-user-interaction-events

In short, you can use the `Div` model and change its `text` attribute to whatever you want.